# Unable to get heroku $port in dockerfile

Tags: docker, heroku, containers, dockerfile

In docker hub, there is a container which when launched opens a port of 9000 by default. The port can be overridden by passing an enviorment variable *server__port*.

I am trying to pass Heroku $PORT value in the dockerfile as shown below:

```
ENV server__port=$PORT
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD start.sh
```

When the start.sh executes, I can see a log where server__port is shown as blank.

If I put a random value of '8889' in the server__port environment variable then in the logs I can see 8889 value assigned to server__port.

I tried to use ARG as shown below, and unfortunately got blank value in server__port variable.

```
ARG PORT
ENV server__port=$PORT
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD start.sh
```

How do I get Heroku port value and set in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out,
I had to export the variable as shown below.

The variable would define the port that would be used by the application.
The command is

```
CMD export CONF_listener__port=$PORT && sh ./start.sh && sh ./startServer.sh -Dclearreports.config="$DEFAULT_CONFIG" -Dsetupautoexecution=true
```